# Why am I not able to add YouTube ad breaks?

Tags: youtube, ads

Whenever I try to insert an add break it disappears and saving changes doesn't help. Why is that? My video is longer than 10 minutes.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by disabling adblock.